# Saudi Arabia (ar-SA) language add to google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying testing a calendar from a client with a language ar-sa (Saudi Arabic), but i'm not able to set that language in chrome. I'm able to set language only arabic  (ar) but not ar-sa.

Is there a option to add this language ar-sa in chrome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pick the specific locale in the Chrome Settings interface.

However, the [Language options](http://chrome://settings/languages) provided by the interface control the [`Accept-Language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) header sent with all HTTP requests. Each language option is mapped to a locale code. In the case of Arabic, you will just get `ar`, as the country is not an option here.

You can modify this header with the [Quick Language Switcher extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-language-switcher/pmjbhfmaphnpbehdanbjphdcniaelfie). You can just add a new locale code to the options list in the extension, and disable the others. This works by simply modifying the header of all requests using the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders` event.